# Azure AD MSAL in iframe

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I have a website protected by azure ad and uses msal, i want to access it in iframe, but it looks it does not work. Is there a way to make it work ? Is it related to the redirect url or other issue ?

Comment: Not quite sure your requirement, do you want to pop up the Azure AD login page in an iframe instead of being redirect to Azure AD login page?

Comment: In fact I have a website protected by azure ad msal and every thing is working correctly, now that website is included in another one as iframe,  the authentication is not working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot authenticate the user inside iframe meaning you cannot use redirect APIs for user interaction with the identity provider.

You can start with creating your own customer page and allow the user to enter the credentials and then authenticate the user. When the user enters their credentials and clicks on login, the server will return OK (if email/password is correct). After that you should save the token in localstorage and then set isAuthenticated = true.

If you are using the Auth code flow, then you should do the authentication in the outer real page not inside the iframe. Then you will have to login once your authenticated. The concept is that you must fully redirect to the Auth pages in azure ad not in iframe.

> You can achieve single sign-on between iframed and parent apps with
> the same-origin and with cross-origin if you pass an account hint from
> the parent app to the iframed app.

Learn more [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/iframe-usage.md#:%7E:text=Using%20MSAL%20in%20iframed%20apps%20By%20default%2C%20MSAL,redirect%20APIs%20for%20user%20interaction%20with%20the%20IdP%3A)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify in the auth config to allow redirects in IFrame
https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/modules/_azure_msal_browser.html